# Creating pagination not working

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am creating pagination in extjs 3.1
but some reason it is not working.
Please what i am doing wrong.
I made page count=5. 
Pagination count is coming correctly.means it is showing number of pages at bottom is coming.

But grid is showing all data.
My code is as follow

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        root : 'data',
        totalProperty : 'total',
        idProperty : 'facId',
        fields : [ "address1", "address2", "city", "country", "ehsContact",
                "facilityManager", "facilityProduct", "facilityType", "fax",
                "facId", "name", "phone", "state", "subGroupA", "subGroupB",
                "zipCode", {
                    name : 'businessUnitId',
                    mapping : 'businessVO.businessId'
                }, {
                    name : 'businessUnitName',
                    mapping : 'businessVO.businessName'
                } ],

        proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url : 'facility.do?method=getAllFacility'
        })
    });

    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        width : 700,
        height : 500,
        title : 'ExtJS.com - Browse Forums',
        store : store,
        trackMouseOver : false,
        disableSelection : true,
        loadMask : true,

        columns : [ {
            id : 'facId',
            header : "facId",
            dataIndex : 'facId',
            sortable : true
        }, {
            header : "fax",
            dataIndex : 'fax',
            width : 100,
            sortable : true
        }, {
            header : "state",
            dataIndex : 'state',
            sortable : true
        }, {
            id : 'address1',
            header : "address1",
            dataIndex : 'address1',
            sortable : true
        } ],

        viewConfig : {
            forceFit : true,
        },

        bbar : new Ext.PagingToolbar({
            pageSize : 5,
            store : store,
            displayInfo : true,
            displayMsg : 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg : "No topics to display"
        })
    });

    store.load({
        params : {
            start : 0,
            limit : 5
        }
    });

    centerPanel = Ext.getCmp('centerlPanel');
    centerPanel.add({
        layout : 'border',
        region : 'center',
        layout : 'fit',
        items : grid
    });
    centerPanel.doLayout();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have always found with Pagination (using JSON/PHP/MySQL) that I have to return the total, and then force my database queries to have a limit on them.  That is what the params of start and limit are for.

```
store.load({
    params : {
        start : 0,
        limit : 5
    }
});
```

Then the query on the database would be

```
     $start = (integer) (isset($_POST['start']) ? $_POST['start'] : $_GET['start']);
       $end = (integer) (isset($_POST['limit']) ? $_POST['limit'] : $_GET['limit']);
$limitquery = $query." LIMIT ".$start.",".$end;
```

(this is for PHP/MySQL)
Then the page sends the appropriate start/end to go through your data. Then the server/database would sort your return.  If you are wanting to use like a client side memory database, you will still need to find a way to do this method.  If you are concerned with the workload this will put on your servers, I have found this is a very small workload on our MySQL database using the `LIMIT` method.

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS3 natively only supports remote paging (so you must handle it on server side). AFAIK `pageSize` parameter is used only to count number of pages, current page and as one of arguments for request (so you can get it's value on server). If you serve more than 5 rows from server - all will be visible.

You can fix it by implementing paging on server or by using `PagingStore` (here is example solution for this second approach: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?71532-Ext.ux.data.PagingStore-v0.5)

Comment: is there any way to use memorypagination? because for every for next item going to server will be costly?

Comment: I don't want to server every time, like datatable is availble in jquery, is there something like that is availble in extjs